# Unity Prime31 prompt for photo is crashing on iOS 10 and XCode 8

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, prime31

Calling EtceteraBinding.promptForPhoto resulting in immediate crash on iOS 10.

```
public void TakePhotoTapped() {

    #if UNITY_IOS
    EtceteraBinding.promptForPhoto(0.2f, PhotoPromptType.Camera, 0.8f, true);
    #endif

}
```

Xcode spits out this log. It does look like some sort of permission issue? Please help.

```
2016-10-11 11:46:35.758167 xxx[1643:458841] invalid mode 'kCFRunLoopCommonModes' provided to CFRunLoopRunSpecific - break on _CFRunLoopError_RunCalledWithInvalidMode to debug. This message will only appear once per execution.
2016-10-11 11:46:49.760643 xxx[1643:458841] [MC] System group container for systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles path is /private/var/containers/Shared/SystemGroup/systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles
2016-10-11 11:46:49.768609 xxx[1643:458841] [MC] Reading from public effective user settings.
2016-10-11 11:47:02.450381 xxx[1643:459135] [access] This app has crashed because it attempted to access privacy-sensitive data without a usage description.  The app's Info.plist must contain an NSCameraUsageDescription key with a string value explaining to the user how the app uses this data.
```

Comment: Post the stacktrace.

Comment: It is self explanatory in the logs, add the key `NSCameraUsageDescription` key with `Using Camera to capture photo` in the `info.plist`. It is now mandatory from the apple that you need to provide an explanation for your usage in info.plist.

Comment: This will require manual edit in xcode after every build from Unity. Something definitely need to avoid as it will disable this project from being used in Unity Cloud Build

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is related to new iOS 10 Privacy Settings requirement. You must declare ahead of time any access to private data or your App will crash.

You can add a usage key to your app’s Info.plist together with a purpose string or add a script that will do it for you in Unity for all your builds.

Xcode Info.plist tab:
[image: Info.plist]

SO for each framework you have to declare it's use and enter a string message that is shown to the user.

You can also add a post processing script in your Assets/Editor folder, where you declare all features used - this will automatically add them to Info.plist:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEditor.Callbacks;
using System.Collections;
using System.IO;
using UnityEditor.iOS.Xcode;


public class ChangeIOSplistFile : MonoBehaviour {

    [PostProcessBuild]
    public static void ChangeXcodePlist(BuildTarget buildTarget, string pathToBuiltProject) {

        if (buildTarget == BuildTarget.iOS) {

            // Get plist
            string plistPath = pathToBuiltProject + "/Info.plist";
            PlistDocument plist = new PlistDocument();
            plist.ReadFromString(File.ReadAllText(plistPath));

            // Get root
            PlistElementDict rootDict = plist.root;
            var cameraKey = "NSCameraUsageDescription";
            rootDict.CreateDict (cameraKey);
            rootDict.SetString (cameraKey, "Enter your description here.");

            var galleryKey = "NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription";
            rootDict.CreateDict (galleryKey);

            rootDict.SetString (galleryKey, "Enter your description here.");

            // Write to file
            File.WriteAllText(plistPath, plist.WriteToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thats it! Thank you!

Comment: Any plans to add photo library settings(NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription) to Unity? The camera one is already there, so dont have to remember to manually edit the pinfo file!